# Is it acceptable to use **kwargs and a decorator to prevent repetitive code?

Tags: python, api, decorator

I'm currently writing an api library in python and I'm wondering if the following code is too unpythonic:

```
@accepts('video_id', 'reference_id', 'page_size', 'page_number',
         'get_item_count', 'fields', 'video_fields', 'custom_fields',
         'media_delivery', 'output')
@requires('video_id', 'reference_id')
def find_related_videos(self, **params):
    return ItemCollection(read_request(params))
```

The `accepts` decorator throws an error if any kwargs not in the the list are passed to the method. It also does validation for certain keywords.

The `requires` decorator ensures that those keyword arguments are present.

Not having the keyword args in the method definition is bugging me. However, having to build the params dictionary manually for each method also seems annoying. Also, there is validation code that is the same for every instance of the `video_fields` argument passed to a method, so I can call that from the accepts decorator to avoid repeating myself.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely put the required fields in the method signature:

```
def find_related_videos(self, video_id, reference_id, **params):
    params.update({'video_id': video_id, 'reference_id': reference_id})
    return ItemCollection(read_request(params))
```

If possible, I'd even modify read_request to take keyword arguments as well:

```
def find_related_videos(self, video_id, reference_id, **params):
    return ItemCollection(read_request(video_id=video_id, reference_id=reference_id, **params))
```

As far as acceptable params go, personally I wouldn't throw errors for invalid params -- I'd just ignore the ones I didn't need.

Comment: I know there is some matter of taste here, but it seems that if the caller is passing a variable the caller is expecting that variable to matter and it would be unexpected to the caller for it to be ignored.  This could lead to unexpected results and that is not a good thing.  I think generally it is better to throw an error and force the programmer to see what matters than blithely ignore parameters and surprise the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

How about this solution?

```
def check_params(params):
    # Do whatever check you want to do on params
    return dict((k, v) for k, v in params
                if v is not None and k != "self")

def find_related_videos(self, video_id, reference_id, page_size=None,
                        page_number=None, get_item_count=None, fields=None,
                        video_fields=None, custom_fields=None,
                        media_delivery=None, output=None):
    params = check_prams(locals())
    return ItemCollection(read_request(params))
```

This will leave checking for acceptable and required parameters to Python, while facitlitating custom tests in `check_params()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it without the decorators.  Much easier for readers to follow the codes executation path without decorators:

```
required = set(['video_id', 'reference_id'])
acceptable = required.union(set(['page_size', 'page_number', 'get_item_count', 'fields', 'video_fields', 'custom_fields', 'media_delivery', 'output']))

def find_related_videos(self, **params): 
    if not (required.issubset(set(params.keys())) or set(params.keys()).issubset(acceptable)):
        raise Exception("Some exception")
    return ItemCollection(read_request(params))
```

This will check to see if all kwargs' keys are in the `acceptable` set and has at least the `required` args.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to do this:

```
def find_related_videos(self, video_id, reference_id, ...)
```

then you could still use a decorator to check the validity of the arguments, and leave the interpreter to enforce the rest for you.  There are some trade-offs though.

- Using positional arguments you no longer allow the caller to specify the arguments in any order.  If you are basically reading in a dictionary and passing it, or something like that, this could be a problem.
- It's harder to write your `@accepts` (or `@validate`) decorator to check the validity of the arguments in the same general way.  It can still be done by using the `inspect.getargspec` function, and I've done something similar before, but it'll take you some time to get it working.  My decorator to automatically match HTTP GET parameters to function arguments is complicated, but it works.